# CV - How to put article type projects on CV

Tags: cv

I will going to apply for masters (in physics) and I am trying to write a CV. I have wrote two "article type" papers during these years with my advisors. I am wondering how can I put them under my CV ?

Answer (score 1):

Just make a separate category for "Articles Published" and include full references. If they weren't refereed then this would probably be better than mixing them with publications that were. If it isn't obvious from the names or venues that they are not refereed, then you should probably add that to the classification. "Unrefereed Articles Published".

Normally the CV is a categorized list of things, possibly with some explanations. The categories are normally up to you.